# Using ngIf without an extra element in Angular 2

Tags: html, templates, angular

Can I use `ngIf` without an extra container element?

```
<tr *ngFor="...">
  <div *ngIf="...">
    ...
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!...">
    ...
  </div>
</tr>
```

It doesn't work in a table because that would make invalid HTML.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

`ng-container` is preferred over `template`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="expression">
```

See:

[Angular 2 ng-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547858/angular-2-ng-container)

https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2303

Comment: You should add a sample "generate" HTML snippet, to make it clear that an HTML <ng-container> element doesn't get created.

Comment: I come here twice a day. I can't get to stick that in my head.

Comment: `ng-container` seems to generate a `div` in our case?

Answer (score 21):

I found a method for that on: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template.

You can simply use the `<template>` tag and replace `*ngIf` with `[ngIf]` like this.

```
<template [ngIf]="...">
  ...
</template>
```

Comment: good but *ngIf itslef creates an `template` tag ,by default angular directives prefix with * creates an template tag. so both are same `[ngIf] and *ngIf`

Comment: With `*ngIf` you have an element inside the template, you do not if you write the `template` yourself. Under certain circumstances the extra element could interfere.

Comment: Can we put `template` tag inside, `tr`/`td` tag?

Comment: Yes it's kind of a special element. Per definition it's not allowed https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3 but it will work and render. If Iam using *ngIf it isn't working btw. but with [ngIf] it does. May I ask if you can tell me why that is?

Comment: @sascha10000 Because having `*ngIf="foo"` is equivalent to the wrapping `<template [ngIf]="foo">` tag. In short, `template` + `[]` == `*`, so `[]` != `*`. `*` makes sense in any element *except* `template`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put `div` directly inside `tr`, that would make invalid HTML. `tr` can only have `td`/`th`/`table` element in it & inside them you could have other HTML elements.

You could slightly change your HTML to have `*ngFor` over `tbody` & have `ngIf` over `tr` itself like below.

```
<tbody *ngFor="...">
  <tr *ngIf="...">
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr  *ngIf="!...">
    ...
  </tr>
  ..
</tbody>
```

Comment: It would basically solve the problem but you'll trade off the core ability you get with tbody. If you have a big table you can fix the head an just scroll the tbody. Your tbody would have the role of tr and tr would have the role of an additional wrapper. If there's no need for scrolling and fixing the head at top this is a pragmatic solution. My reference for what I said: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <tr *ngIf="item.active">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
 </ng-container>
```

Here, I have iterate loop in ng container so it will not create extra dom and later in tr tag check condition if I want to render or not.

Answer (score 0):

adding brackets resolves this issue

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="(!variable| async)"></ng-container>
```