# <ng-container> vs <template>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

`ng-container` is mentioned in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container) but I'm still trying to understand how it works and what are use cases.

It is particularly mentioned in [`ngPlural`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgPlural) and [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) directives.

Does `<ng-container>` do the same thing as `<template>` or does it depend on whether a directive was written to use one of them?

Are

```html
<ng-container *ngPluralCase="'=0'">there is nothing</ng-container>
```

and

```html
<template [ngPluralCase]="'=0'">there is nothing</template>
```

supposed to be the same?

How do we choose one of them?

How can `<ng-container>` be used in a custom directive?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

### Edit : Now it is [documented](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#hosting-a-directive-without-a-dom-element)

> ### `<ng-container>` to the rescue
>
> The Angular `<ng-container>` is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.
>
> (...)
>
> The `<ng-container>` is a syntax element recognized by the Angular parser. It's not a directive, component, class, or interface. It's more like the curly braces in a JavaScript if-block:
>
> ```
>   if (someCondition) {
>      statement1; 
>      statement2;
>      statement3;
>     }
> ```
>
> Without those braces, JavaScript would only execute the first statement when you intend to conditionally execute all of them as a single block. The `<ng-container>` satisfies a similar need in Angular templates.

### Original answer:

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9197) :

> `<ng-container>` is a logical container that can be used to group nodes but is not rendered in the DOM tree as a node.

> `<ng-container>` is rendered as an HTML comment.

so this angular template :

```
<div>
    <ng-container>foo</ng-container>
<div>
```

will produce this kind of output :

```
<div>
    <!--template bindings={}-->foo
<div>
```

So `ng-container` is useful when you want to conditionaly append a group of elements (ie using `*ngIf="foo"`) in your application but **don't want to wrap them with another element**.

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="true">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div>Content</div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

will then produce :

```
<div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good point. I guess that it differs from `<template>` when it's used without directives. `<template>` would just produce `<!--template bindings={}-->` in this case.

Comment: actually, `<template></template>`will produce `<script></script>` [see this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template)

Comment: It wasn't so in my case. Even if there is `<script>` during compilation, it is removed afterwards, there are no extra tags in DOM. I believe that the manual contains deprecated information or is just wrong on that. Any way, thanks for pointing the main difference between <ng-container> and <template>.

Comment: Before release, Angular rendered `<script></script>`. It's been rendering something like `<!--template bindings={}-->` for quite a while. The docs will be fixed soon.

Comment: the documentation no longer contains the explanatation. I tried to find a documentation page about `ng-container`, I didn't find anyting. Is it something deprecated, why is it not documentated ?

Answer (score 49):

The documentation (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#star-template) gives the following example. Say we have template code like this:

```
<hero-detail *ngIf="currentHero" [hero]="currentHero"></hero-detail>
```

Before it will be rendered, it will be "de-sugared". That is, the asterix notation will be transcribed to the  notation:

```
<template [ngIf]="currentHero">
  <hero-detail [hero]="currentHero"></hero-detail>
</template>
```

If 'currentHero' is truthy this will be rendered as

```
<hero-detail> [...] </hero-detail>
```

But what if you want an conditional output like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1><br>
<p>text</p>
```

.. and you don't want the output be wrapped in a container.

You could write the de-sugared version directly like so:

```
<template [ngIf]="showContent">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>text</p><br>
</template>
```

And this will work fine. However, now we need ngIf to have brackets [] instead of an asterix *, and this is confusing (https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2303)

For that reason a different notation was created, like so:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showContent"><br>
  <h1>Title</h1><br>
  <p>text</p><br>
</ng-container>
```

Both versions will produce the same results (only the h1 and p tag will be rendered). The second one is preferred because you can use *ngIf like always.

Comment: Nice explanation, it provides overview of *How `ng-container` directive idea came*, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of behavior, this

```
<template [ngIf]="show">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
</template>
```

is equivalent to

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
</ng-container>
```

---

So which one should you use?

`ng-container` is preferred because then we preserve the convention that structural directives are denoted with an asterisk, e.g. `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, etc.

---

However, in some cases, we *have* to use `template` instead. For instance, in cases where you need to reference the `template` tag by template name, e.g. `<template #templateName>`.

---

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762236/7123519 for a more verbose answer.

Answer (score 0):

Imo use cases for `ng-container` are simple replacements for which a custom template/component would be overkill. In the API doc they mention the following

> use a ng-container to group multiple root nodes

and I guess that's what it is all about: grouping stuff.

Be aware that the `ng-container` directive falls away instead of a template where its directive wraps the actual content.

Comment: Do you have a link to this mention? Only seeing it used in the above linked documentation and plural case documentation at the moment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgPluralCase-directive.html.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

Comment: Thanks, created an issue at the docs site regarding the lack of documentation and referenced this answer: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2553

Comment: The answer isn't really clear on what's the difference from `<template>` which serves the same purpose. FWIW, I could make ngPluralCase work with `<template ngPluralCase="=0">`. But the way that was stated in the question gives me `Can't bind to 'ngPluralCase' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'` in final release. Not sure what this means.

Comment: @estus, ngContainer is imo a predefined template that serves the one and only purpose to group multiple root nodes. It's out of question that you could do this with your own template, however with the additional and unnecessary effort of creating and registering your own component. Something like the curly brackets after an if-condition. You don't need them, but they are quite handy :)

Comment: downvoted -1. ng-container is not about avoiding a custom template, it is about being able to have conditional content that is not wrapped in a container. In fact a custom template will also introduce a wrapper container, namely the directive tag itself.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That sure is a difference that need to be mentioned. I've added the hint to my post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it acts like a `<div>` or `<span>` however even `<span>` messes up with my AngularFlex styling but `ng-container` doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

A use case for it when you want to use a table with *ngIf and *ngFor - As putting a div in td/th will **make the table element misbehave** -. I faced this problem and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860933/ngif-and-ngfor-on-td-td-element) was the answer.

Comment: But the same thing can be achieved with `<template [ngIf]...>`. The question was the difference between these two approaches.

Comment: oh, my bad, it seems to be answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529537/ng2-difference-between-ng-container-and-template-tags
they simply say it's just a syntax difference