# Angular2 : Can't bind to 'ngPluralCase' since it isn't a known property of 'x'

Tags: angular, typescript, pluralize

First, this question is **not** a duplicate, most answers to questions like "Cannot bind to 'x'..." are about unimported modules, I've **already imported the right one(s)**.

I'm following angular.io's doc about [`ngPlural`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgPlural-directive.html) and [`ngPluralCase`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgPluralCase-directive.html) directives:

> ```
> <some-element [ngPlural]="value">
>   <ng-container *ngPluralCase="'=0'">...</ng-container>
>   <ng-container *ngPluralCase="'other'">...</ng-container>
> </some-element>
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> exported from @angular/common/index, defined in @angular/common/src/directives/ng_plural.ts

When I try to run this code I get an error [(see it in plnkr)](https://embed.plnkr.co/LzhoDs/):

> Can't bind to 'ngPluralCase' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.

**main.ts :**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { Component, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template:`
  <div [ngPlural]="1">
      <ng-container *ngPluralCase="'=0'">...</ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngPluralCase="'other'">...</ng-container>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
class AppComponent {

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  exports: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I imported `BrowserModule` (which exports `CommonModule`, but I also tried importing `CommonModule` directly) in my `AppModule`, and as you can see, the error is about `ngPluralCase` and not `ngPlural` which is in the same module and used without problem...

So my question is :

Does anyone knows what is happening here ? Is it a bug related to the "experimental" state of these directives or am I missing something ?

**PS**: I'm using angular v2.1.0

Comment: I see you've opened an issue, good call. For some reason I've failed to use it like that but had success in using it like `<template ngPluralCase="other">` (also a bit shorter). A question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547858/angular-2-ng-container) still hasn't got a fair answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment I Opened an [issue on the Github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12363), because it really seems broken....

**Edit** This is the [answer that I got](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12363#issuecomment-254491661) from my Github issue:

> The problem here is actually that the NgPluralCase directive uses an @Attribute injection and because `ng-container` are virtual nodes, attributes can not be retrieved on them.
>
> You have to use a `<template>` tag in this case, the docs will be fixed as part of a pending PR.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is [angular.io](https://angular.io) right now is outdated, at least example of [NgPlural](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgPlural-directive.html).
Example below works with v2.4.4:

```
<some-element [ngPlural]="value">
  <template ngPluralCase="=0">there is nothing</template>
  <template ngPluralCase="=1">there is one</template>
  <template ngPluralCase="few">there are a few</template>
</some-element>
```