# ng2 - Difference between ng-container and ng-template tags

Tags: angular

Can someone please illustrate the difference between using `<ng-container>` and `<ng-template>` elements?

I could not find documentation for `NgContainer` and don't quite understand the difference between template tag.

A code example of each would greatly help.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Both of them are at the moment (2.x, 4.x) used to group elements together without having to introduce another element which will be rendered on the page (such as `div` or `span`).

`template`, however, requires nasty syntax. For example,

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```

would become

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</template>
```

You can use `ng-container` instead since it follow the nice `*` syntax which you expect and are probably already familiar with.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ng-container>
```

You can find more details by reading [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11994).

---

Note that in 4.x `<template>` is deprecated and is changed to `<ng-template>`.

---

Use

- [`<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer) if you need a helper element for nested structural directives like [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) or [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) or if you want to wrap more than one element inside such a structural directive;
- `<ng-template>` if you need a view "snippet" that you want to stamp at various places using `ngForTemplate`, [`ngTemplateOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet), or [`createEmbeddedView()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createEmbeddedView).

Comment: "Nasty syntax" might be a bit exaggerated :D It's normal syntax for passing values to `@Input()`s. `*` is more convenient of course. But you are right, `<ng-container>` was introduced because the syntax differences caused quite some confusion.

Comment: <ng-container> doesn't introduce new element in DOM. What about <ng-template>? Please clarify in your answer.

Comment: This page helped me figure out what is what: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/.

Comment: How can I use the n-container with ngFor to render rows of a table ? i am trying this but it is not working. I want to render rows conditionally so i can have ngFor on the row element.

Comment: Except it's incorrect. `ng-template` is not an Angular element.

Answer (score 33):

`ng-template` is used for the structural directive like `ng-if`, `ng-for` and `ng-switch`. If you use it without the structural directive, nothing happens and it will render.

`ng-container` is used when you don't have a suitable wrapper or parent container. In most cases, we are using `div` or `span` as a container but in such cases when we want to use multiple structural directives. But we can't use more than one structural directive on an element, in that case, `ng-container` can be used as a container

Answer (score 24):

**ng-template**
The `<ng-template>` is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed directly. Use for structural directives such as: ngIf, ngFor, ngSwitch,..
**Example**:

```
<div *ngIf="hero" class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
```

Angular translates the *ngIf attribute into a `<ng-template>` element, wrapped around the host element, like this.

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <div class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

**ng-container**
Use as a grouping element when there is no suitable host element.
**Example:**

```html
<div>
  Pick your favorite hero
  (<label><input type="checkbox" checked (change)="showSad = !showSad">show sad</label>)
</div>
<select [(ngModel)]="hero">
  <span *ngFor="let h of heroes">
    <span *ngIf="showSad || h.emotion !== 'sad'">
      <option [ngValue]="h">{{h.name}} ({{h.emotion}})</option>
    </span>
  </span>
</select>
```

This will not work. Because some HTML elements require all immediate children to be of a specific type. For example, the `<select>` element requires  children. You can't wrap the options in a conditional  or a `<span>`.

Try this :

```html
<div>
  Pick your favorite hero
  (<label><input type="checkbox" checked (change)="showSad = !showSad">show sad</label>)
</div>
<select [(ngModel)]="hero">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let h of heroes">
    <ng-container *ngIf="showSad || h.emotion !== 'sad'">
      <option [ngValue]="h">{{h.name}} ({{h.emotion}})</option>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

This will work.

More information: [Angular Structural Directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#what-are-structural-directives)

Comment: this is the easiest to understand answer!

Answer (score 14):

**ng-template show true value.**

```
<ng-template>
    This is template block
</ng-template>
```

> Output:

**ng-container show without condition also show content.**

```
<ng-container>
    This is container.
</ng-container>
```

> Output:
>   This is container.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-template` as the name implies, denotes a *template*. By itself it doesn't render anything. We can use a `ng-container` to provide a placeholder to render a template *dynamically*.

Another use-case for `ng-template` is that we can use it to nest multiple structural directives together.
You can find great examples here in this blog post: [angular ng-template/ng-container](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

Answer (score 2):

I like `<ng-container>` as a way to separate "logic" from "markup" as much as possible in the Angular .component.html files.

(partial) example to render rows of an html table:

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ product.productName }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.productCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.releaseDate }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.starRating }}</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

That way, if I want to change from an HTML `<table>` to something else, such as a bunch of `<div>` with flexbox styling, I don't need to "carve out" the looping logic (or risk losing it completely) from inside the `<tr>`.  It also keeps the looping (ngFor) logic from being partially obscured by the normal html.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, `ng-container` is like a Higher component of **React**, which only aids in the rendering of its child elements.

`ng-template` is basically for internal implementation of **Angular**, wherein anything inside the `ng-template` is completely ignored while rendering and it basically becomes a comment on view source. This is supposed to be used with Angular's internal directives like `ngIf`, `ngSwitch` etc.