# *ngIf and *ngFor on <td></td> element

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a situation where I need *ngIf and *ngFor directive on the same element. I found lot of answers on the stackoverlow but none for the this type of situation.

I have a table in which I'm looping through the array of objects and dynamically write cells in header:

```
 <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td *ngFor="let item of headerItems" *ngIf="item.visible">{{ item?.name }}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to show/hide  if object contains visible set to true. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use the `<ng-container>` helper element for that.

```ts
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of headerItems" >
 <td *ngIf="item.visible">{{ item?.name }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

It is not added to the DOM.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. Can you please explain a little bit what is exactly ng-container in this situation. I've used it for transclusion in components.

Comment: It works just fine in case someone is having trouble with table tag. Another alternative is to replace table with a div tag

Comment: Cool answer - all works. 

I just wanna jump in and say that this Ang 2 approach is complete bs lol.
Y U DO THIS ANG?

Comment: @Marko no sure what you mean. Most people who complain about Angular didn't really try to understand what it is for. Angular 2 isn't a replacement for AngularJS, it's something new with a different goal.

Comment: Yap, that coming from AngularJS expectation is probably the cause of my complains lol. Cause in AngJS, you could add multiple bindings.
All though, doesn't it seem a bit too much that you have to add another element for each Ang 2 binding ...

Comment: When you understand what happens behind the scenes you can't imagine it being any other way ;-). Check the tutorials about structural directives. I haven't used AngularJS at all, therefore I didn't have very specific expectations.

Answer (score 11):

Günter Zöchbauer's answer is great. I've also found one more solution.

```
<td *ngFor="let item of headerItems" [hidden]="!item.visible">{{ item?.name }}</td>
```

But this one will be parsed inside html.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **template** element also:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="headerItems ">
   <td *ngIf="item.visible">{{ item?.name }}</td>
</template>
```

This will work for you.

Comment: BTW this is now called `<ng-template>` in angular 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ngclass for that

```
 .hidecell{
     display:none;
  }
<td *ngFor="let item of headerItems"  [ngClass]="{hidecell:item.isVisible}">
 {{ item?.name }}
</td>
```